# Ajax call does not receive response of previous session hit

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I am requesting an ajax call and a java method runs in loop. Before method finishes, session logs out. When i log in next session and the previous session java method return response, ajax does not recieve the response. I have to reload the page when previous session response comes back to ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "downloadAudit",
    type : "GET",
    data : {auditId : templateAuditId, queryStatus : aStatus},
    beforeSend : function(xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                                    
    },
    success: function(status){
        if(status == "Success"){
            window.location = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getAuditManagement";
        }
        
    }
});
```

Comment: please add your relevant java code too

Comment: You cannot receive the response from a request that has already happened and failed.